# How to multiply values from unrelated tables in Tableau?

Tags: powerbi, tableau-api

I have two tables:

1. **Roads** (ID, Length), which contains the following:

   ```
    ID: 1, Length: 3
    ID: 2, Length: 6
   ```
2. **MaintenanceActivities** (ID, TimeRequired)

   ```
    ID: 1, TimeRequired: 5
    ID: 2, TimeRequired: 10
   ```

I would like to create a matrix table in Tableau or Power BI, which lists all the MaintenanceActivities as rows and all of the Roads as columns. For the values, I would like to multiply the Length by the TimeRequired. That way, I could calculate how much time is required, based on the length of the roads.

This would give me the following output:

Road ID 1 would have 3x5=15, 3x10=30 for a grand total of 45.

Road ID 2 would have 6x5=30, 6x10=60 for a grand total of 90.

I'm struggling with this because the tables are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Select ID,  length  *( select sum(timerequired)  from maintenanceActivity) from  roads

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a cross product of your two tables — that includes every combination of a row from the left table and a row from the right table. Some SQL flavors let you put the word CROSS before JOIN as a shortcut.

In Tableau, just create a data source that connects to both tables and joins them. For the join key, you can use a simple calculation to define a constant value for both the left and right tables. Then you can make a join condition that is always true, like 1=1.

The resulting data source will have one row for every possible combination of road and maintenance activity, so you can build your table.

Comment: FYI, a similar strategy would work in Power BI as well.